Override `ignoresSafeArea` in overlay
I have a view with a TextField overlay that responds to keyboard events (the default behavior in iOS 14.2+). When the TextField is in focus, the keyboard pushes this view, along with its overlay, "up":
struct CommentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "dog.jpeg")!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 500)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        // I want this TextField to _respect_ the keyboard event
                        TextField("", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
                            .padding([.horizontal], 16)
                            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    }
                }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) // The parent view to _ignore_ keyboard event
    }
}

However, I want only the overlay to respond to keyboard events, not the parent view itself. That is, I want the overlay to move up within the parent view while the parent view stays where it is.
In the above code, you can see I added ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to the parent view, but this gets applied to the TextField overlay as well. Is there a way to override this?
Original view without keyboard

Without .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard), parent view gets "pushed" up:


Attempting to use ZStack:
The Image enlarges when the keyboard comes into play:
struct CommentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "dog.jpeg")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TextField("", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .focused($isFocused)
                        .submitLabel(.done)
                        .onChange(of: text, initial: false) {
                            guard isFocused else { return }
                            guard text.contains("\n") else { return }
                            isFocused = false
                            text = text.replacing("\n", with: "")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
                        .padding([.horizontal], 16)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    
                }
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .frame(width: 350, height: 500)
            .onTapGesture {
                isFocused = false
            }
                
        }
    }
}


@Sweeper I added a screenshot to better convey that the TextField is strictly a children of the parent view (the Image in this case). I quickly attempted using ZStack as you suggested but I'm getting weird behaviors. namely, the image is enlarged when keyboard is showing.

You'd need to rearrange the view hierarchy a bit. Make the overlay a "parent" of the image that already has .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard). In other words, apply .overlay after .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard).
A somewhat tricky part is the clip shape. Presumably, you want the clip shape to not avoid the keyboard too. Instead of clipShape, you can use mask, which allows you to pass in a view that ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard).
VStack {
    Spacer()
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "1")!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 350, height: 500)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    TextField("", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
}
.mask {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
}


This only works if the Image is on the bottom? There's no canonical way of handling it?

@bli00 if the image is somewhere else, you can still position the text field correctly with alignment guides and other things. Yes, you’re right that there is no canonical way of doing this.
